# UIWebView - how to display iPhone-sized content on an iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, uiwebview

I have an iPad app where I want to display a UIWebView in a compartmentalized space on my view controller. I made the width 320px like the iPhone, and want the content to render exactly how it would on an iPhone. However, any pages I load still render in the full iPad size.

[image: iPad WebView Not Resizing]

I've tried setting the user agent via NSUserDefaults and while this helps on the first page, it
1.) Doesn't work after you click on a link, as in picture 1
2.) Renders sites like google slightly differently than if you were to load google up on your iPhone Safari browser.

```
NSString* userAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1 like Mac OS X)";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"UserAgent" : userAgent}];
```

I've tried setting the scale page to fit `UIWebView.scalesPageToFit`, but this just scales the iPad version of the page in the window, making the content illegible.

I also tried to use Javascript to fix the page after loading, but that doesn't work either. It renders sites like google slightly differently than if you were to load google up on your iPhone Safari browser.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView {
    if(webView.frame.size.width < webView.window.frame.size.width) {
        // width=device-width results in a wrong viewport dimension for webpages displayed in a popover
        NSString *jsCmd = @"var viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]');";
        jsCmd = [jsCmd stringByAppendingFormat:@"viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=%i, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1');", (NSUInteger)webView.frame.size.width];
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCmd];
    }
    // stop network indicator
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

[image: User Agent set to "iPhone"]

instead of like this render on my iPhone 5S:

[image: iPhone rendering of Google page]

Any help with how I can achieve an iPhone style UIWebView in an iPad would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**Edit:**

I tried setting the zoom factor to only the width of the iPad, but it only makes the entire iPad version of the page fit the width, with illegible content. Still not looking like the iPhone above.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGSize contentSize = webView.scrollView.contentSize;
    CGSize viewSize = webView.bounds.size;

    float rw = viewSize.width / contentSize.width;

    webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = rw;
    webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = rw;
    webView.scrollView.zoomScale = rw;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I think I solved my own issue. This required three steps in order to work for ios7.

1.) Setting the User-Agent to iPhone instead of iPad. I'd like to not set this globally, but not sure how to adjust the header on a per request basis especially when the user is clicking on links in the UIWebView. I'd also like to be able to be able to get the default userAgent of the iPad and just change out iPad for iPhone so that the rest of the user-agent string is correct for the device, like people running iPhone OS 7_1_1.

```
NSString* userAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11B651";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"UserAgent" : userAgent}];
```

2.) Running Javascript to change the device width of the viewport of the page.

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]').setAttribute('content', 'width=%dpx;', false);", (int) webView.frame.size.width]];
```

3.) Scaling Page to Fit

Pages that do not have responsive design will scale to fit on the iPhone Safari browser, so we kept that enabled as well in storyboard. This alone does not solve the issue however as explained in my original question.

Now pages render in the proper size as they would on an iPhone.

**Couple things to note.** The page now renders its content the same way and with the same attributes as it would on an iPhone (big text, search bar expands to cover Google icon when edited). It doesn't scale the contents to the fit the page in the height, but does adjust to fit the width (which is what I wanted).

[image: Working version]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UIWebView.scalesPageToFit` property. This will resize webpage to fit size of webview.

Comment: I already mentioned the effect of that in my question. All that does is scale the iPad-sized page to have the entire contents of the page fit in the window (both width and height). This makes the page illegible and the user has to zoom back in to see the page, and it is still rendered in iPad sizes. That is not the effect I am going for.